# how to prevent new element being appended repeatedly in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Currently I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_device(device)
   {
    var mylink = window.location.href + "&name=" + device.value;
    window.location.replace(mylink);
    window.history.back
    }
</script>
```

When a variable pass in, it will add as a new element into the url. Is there any way that I could possibly pass the variable in smartly as it will not just append repeatedly to the existing address?
I have tried to do it like

```
const url = window.location
window.location.replace(url.hostname + url.pathname + url.search + "&name=" + device.value)
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you have multiple search parameters, not just `name` (since you're using `&`, not `?` at the beginning), use URLSearchParams from the search string, set the new name, and then turn it back into a string:

```
function select_device(device) {
    const { pathname, search } = window.location;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
    params.set('name', device);
    window.location.replace(pathname + '?' + String(params))
}
```